# Repeated measures/pseudoreplication - Comparing all samples against all other samples

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, independence

I am currently analysing some data, and I am not confident that I am going about it in as statistically sound way.

We are trying to determine whether our treatments affect the distance between two groups of samples (n = 10 in each group). We are using a relevant biological mathematical model to calculate distances between all samples in group 1 with all samples in group 2. There are four treatments, and each involves changing one parameter in the mathematical model to re-calculate the distances. The distances calculated from each treatment, are combined into one dataset with the treatment as a variable.

A small dataset looks like this:

```
ID1 <- 1:3
ID2 <- 4:6
treatment <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

dat <- expand.grid("Group1" = ID1, 
                   "Group2" = ID2,
                   "Treatment" = treatment)  
dat$distance <- rnorm(36, mean = 10, sd = 2)
dat
```

Currently, we are determining if there is a difference between the treatment groups by using a linear mixed model:

```
m1 <- lmer(distance ~ Treatment + (1|Group1) + (1|Group2), dat = dat)
```

But since we are comparing all samples in `Group1` with all samples in `Group2`, I didn't know if this is an appropriate way to properly account for the pseudoreplication.

My question is, is this an appropriate way to analyse these data? And, if not, what other analyses should I look in to?

I have searched Cross-Validated to find information about repeated measures or distance matrices, but cannot find an equivalent scenario. Please let me know if this has already been answered.

Thank you!

**Edit:**

These are not physical distances, they are perceptual distances (modelling for a particular animal). So, it's a calculation of how different two samples will look from one another, e.g. a flower and a leaf.  Each distance value can be considered similar to an eigen vector.

Comment: Welcome to CV! Are these physical distances? Why did you calculate distances in the first place, what were the original values? You can clarify by editing your question with the button below it.

Comment: Thank you for editing, but I still don't understand. Is there a stochastic part to your mathematical model? If not, why are you using a statistical model to determine the influence of changing your model, can't you express it analytically? Could you perhaps be more specific than *a treatment*, *a relevant mathematical model*, etc.?

Comment: Hi @FransRodenburg. Thanks for looking into my question! I appreciate your help. There is no stochastic part to the model. I tried to keep the example general because I don't think the details of how the distances between samples were calculated affect my question. But, I think I haven't explained my question well.  Usually when I have a repeated measures its just one variable has repeated measured. Whereas here, every flower is compared with every leaf. With 10 flowers and 10 leaves, this gives 100 comparisons per treatment. I'm not sure if an LMM can account for this pseudoreplication?

Comment: Have you tried including a random effect for the possible combinations only? I think you'd do well to edit your question and include a research question somewhere. For example, if your goal is to assess the distances between different of objects, why not perform classification and assess the differences in class probabilities? Don't get me wrong, your question is clear. But without a goal, it is hard to assess whether the approach is suitable at all.